# Standard class members are invisible - `Type of expression is statically unknown` error

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am getting `Type of expression is statically unknown` error in Eclipse for many standard groovy functions:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.xml.DomToGroovy
```

...

```
                                   v- here
def xmlRequest= new XmlSlurper().parseText(templateString.trim())

def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
                    v- and here
fw<< outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield xmlRequest }
```

Oh, yes, and the question is - what does it mean, please? This error is NOT widely known by google.

The error is real, it is not a problem that would be resolver by itself at run stage. On the contrary, the project won't run. ( it is a test and says : No JUnit tests found )

Comment: Looks like Eclipse can't work out what the type of `xmlRequest` should be...  Can you try `GPathResult xmlRequest = new XmlSlurper().parseText( templateString.trim() )` (note I don't use Eclipse, so may be wrong)

Comment: I think tim_yates is right, maybe you are hitting this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1483 (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

I think *Tim Yates* is right in his comment. It seems something related to type inferencing. I guess you are hitting this bug [GRECLIPSE-1483](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1483): *field initializers are not contributing to type inferencing*.

I've done a small test:

```
package test

import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import org.codehaus.groovy.tools.xml.DomToGroovy

class SimpleTest {
    def templateString = '<test>testing</test>'

    def xmlRequest= new XmlSlurper().parseText(templateString.trim())
}
```

With this, the `trim()` method is underlined. Activating *Groovy Type Checking* (Right-click on file -> Groovy Type Checking -> Type check), the message "Type of expression is statically unknown: trim"

Going a bit further, anotating the class with `@TypeChecked`:

- Multiple markers at this line

  - Groovy:[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method groovy.util.XmlSlurper#parseText(java.lang.Object). Please check if
    the declared type is right and if the method exists.
  - Groovy:[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#trim(). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
  - Type of expression is statically unknown: trim

But if I enclose the code above inside a method, thereby without field initializers, the above errors disappear:

```
@TypeChecked
class SimpleTest {
    def test() {
        def templateString = '<test>testing</test>'
        def xmlRequest= new XmlSlurper().parseText(templateString.trim())
    }
}
```

And without the `@TypeChecked` annotation, the "*Groovy Type Checking*" is not giving this error.

Comment: This is a little odd that @TypeChecked is failing to find XmlSlurper#parseText.  Seems like it should. It could be a groovy bug.

Comment: I raised https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6089 for the groovy bug.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't think it is a groovy bug... It is complaining about XmlSlurper#parseText(java.lang.Object), because it does not exist. Only XmlSlurper#parseText(java.lang.String) exists. The root cause of the problem is that templateString is not inferred to be a String, so neither java.lang.Object#trim() nor XmlSlurper#parseText(Object) exist statically.

Comment: Good point.  I think you're right.  At the very least, this behavior goes against expectations (in the same way the problem exists in greclipse).

Comment: +1. Thank you for the "@TypeChecked" idea. It won't help here but surely will be useful sometimes. As for my project, I had reverted the Groovy installation, installed it back and the problems mentioned disappeared. There are surely some deeper problems, but they look different.